# jQuery cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm developping a web-based mobile application, which communicates with a server and retrieves data from there. I have 2 global variables called `access_token` and `refresh_token` and I want to update their values using cookies, but I have problems writing them. Here is my sample code:

```
function getToken(authCode) {
    var jsonUrl = "URL;
    $.ajax({
        url: jsonUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            $.cookie('access_token', data.access_token, {expires:7, path:"/"});
            $.cookie('refresh_token', data.refresh_token, {expires:7, path:"/"});
        }
    });
}

function valTokens() {
    access_token = $.cookie('access_token');
    refresh_token = $.cookie('refresh_token');
}
```

I get the data from the server correctly (`data.access_token` and `data.refresh_token` are valid) using the first function and then later, when I try to update the values of the global variables calling `valTokens()`, they get the value `undefined`, although the received data is correct.

These are the scripts I use locally:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where and How are you using these function?

Comment: We won't be able to help unless you can post the value of `data`

Comment: Should it not be `var jsonUrl = "URL";` ?

Comment: Please show us exactly where you call both of your methods

Comment: I use the function getToken(authCode) to retrieve an access token from a web server. The value of data is simply { access_token : "UUID" }, where UUID is randomly generated value on the server side. I'm pretty sure, that the value of data is correct, because I have tested it without using cookies. var jsonUrl = "URL"; URL is the local URL from where I retrieve the token.

I call the first function with a button, which calls the following function:

Comment: function oauth(){
    var jsonUrl = "URL-for-the-code";
    $.ajax({
        url: jsonUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            getToken(data.code);
        }
    });
}
The I use another function to put the variable access_token to a query and send it again to the server, the problem is that it's value is undefined. I'm pretty sure that the server side works fine, because I've tested it several times.